# How aws cloudformation package cli gets last run MD5 checksums?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

Below is paragraph from aws cloudformation cli documentation available here. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/package.html

> Before the command uploads artifacts, it checks if the artifacts are
>   already present in the S3 bucket to prevent unnecessary uploads. The
>   command uses MD5 checksums to compare files. If the values match, the
>   command doesn't upload the artifacts. Use the --force flag to skip
>   this check and always upload the artifacts.

My question is how does package command gets MD5 checksums of files to compare from last pipeline run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't care about the last pipeline run per se.

It gets the current packages md5 and compares it agains the md5's of the artifacts present in the s3 bucket.

Comment: How does it know last artifact key in S3? For example, in my template I have two lambda functions. Package command creates two zip files with random names, one for each lambda and uploads to S3. When package command runs next time how does it know which zip file is for which lambda?

Comment: I believe if you have 10 artifacts in the bucket, and upload 2 more (two lambda's) it would make sure the 2 md5's you have do not match any of the md5's of the 10 existing.

Comment: Coming back to add more clarification to answer: trick here is cloudformation package cli uses md5 of zip file as S3 key for that zip file. So in a way cloudformation package cli uses S3 to remember md5 by storing md5 of last run zip as key of that zip.